# Nativescript (angular) not finding module for lazy loading

Tags: javascript, angular, web, angular2-nativescript

I am attempting to lazy load a module in my application. This example is supposed to work on angular, but it is throwing the following error:

`Computed path '/Users/faridgarciayala/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D5EE2284-8088-43A1-A703-1A5C7021DF42/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/0D994956-6311-438F-B459-98BA7424EF1A/routingexample.app/app/one/one.module'`

It is apparently trying to get the module from the emulator.

here is my [repo](https://github.com/faridg18/nativescript-routing)

complete error log:

`CONSOLE ERROR file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:15768:28: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Could not find module './one/one.module'. Computed path '/Users/faridgarciayala/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D5EE2284-8088-43A1-A703-1A5C7021DF42/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/0D994956-6311-438F-B459-98BA7424EF1A/routingexample.app/app/one/one.module'.
require@[native code]
file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/globals/globals.js:81:39
ZoneAwarePromise@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js:902:37
import@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/globals/globals.js:79:27
loadAndCompile@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:18403:33
loadModuleFactory@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:3702:50
load@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:3690:56
file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:2693:55
_tryNext@file:///app/tns_modules/rxjs/inte<…>`

Comment: please share the relevant code here

Answer (score 1):

Try to this for lazy loading routing.

**app-routing.module.ts :-**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";

const routes: Routes = [
{ path: "", redirectTo: "/login", pathMatch: "full" },
{ path: "library", loadChildren: "~/pages/library/library.module#LibraryModule" },
{ path: "login", loadChildren: "~/pages/login/login.module#LoginModule" }
]

@NgModule({
imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**Redirection Code:-**

```
import { NgZone } from "@angular/core";
import { isIOS } from "tns-core-modules/platform";
import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular/router";

constructor(private zone: NgZone,
private _routerExtensions: RouterExtensions){ }

gotoStartPage() {
setTimeout(() => {
    this.zone.run(() => {
        this._routerExtensions.navigate(["library"], {
            clearHistory: (isIOS) ? true : false,
        });
    });
}, 500);
}
```